# how to split acroos the string where neither index nor particular keyword is specfied

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

```
Input: plasticCup()
Output: plastic cup
```

I have a task where i need to split acroos where i get the capital letter in javascript then make it small and then join them all as a word also need to remove the parantheses from them

```
example  Input: plasticCup()
example Output: plastic cup


example Input: sarangTry()
example Output sarang try
```

Comment: `output = input.replace(/([A-Z])|\W/g, (m, c) => c ? \` ${m.toLowerCase()}\` : '');`

Comment: it works please write in answer so that i can accept it can you please explain (/([A-Z])|\W/g, (m, c) => what this means

Comment: `replace` method can take [a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) as a parameter. `c` is the first capture group in the match, and when not matching the only capture group in the RegExp, the value is `undefined`. It's notable, that the example removes all the special characters from the input, not only parenthesis.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do the reverse of what i did as well

Comment: Replace a space and a-z with a capital, and add "()" at the end of the string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp